# How to write complex cypher query in java

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I am new to cypher. When I read someone's code, I find this code:

```
String query="{\"query\":\"START n=node("+id+") return n\",\"params\":{}}"
```

and

```
String query="{\"query\":\"CREATE(n:Employee{props}) return n\",\"params\":{\"props\":{\"name\":\""
            +name+"\",\"address\":\""+address+"\",\"phone\":\""+phone+"\",\"email\":\""+email+"\"," +
            "\"createTime\":\""+time+"\",\"lastModifyTime\":\""+time+"\",\"status\":\""+status+"\"}}}";
```

I find it is to complex to write and easy to be wrong. But I don't how to improve it, can you help me?

Comment: Provide more information - do you use neo4j as embedded or server? How do you execute the query?

Comment: It should be a server. I have HttpClient  executed this query,then get the response,finally return to customer

Answer (score 0):

### Techniques for Controlling Complexity

When complexity of understanding is an issue, you should always look for these.

The simplest you can come across in this case is **Black box abstraction**

- Create a class which has responsibility of creating a query `String` when you provide various properties to it.
- As the structure of the query is standard, you can easily (?) (apologies) write a general method to encompass as many properties as you can (or even some custom property)
- You could call something like

  ```
  queryBin.addProperty(propertyName1, value1);
  queryBin.addProperty(propertyName2, value1);
  queryBin.addProperty(propertyName3, value2);
  ```
- Now you can compose them to a single `String` like following.

  ```
  query = queryBin.composeToString();
  ```

This way you can achieve **improved readability**, suppressed and hidden details (**encapsulation**) and **safety**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I  used to write SQL .I knew something named PrepareStatement,you can wtrite (?) in sql,then use PrepareStatement object to set value,like this :pstemt.setInt(key,value)...but I do not know how to implement it with cypher.Thaks for your help,it helps me a lot

Comment: Just think of it this way. If you can write a query string by hand, you can always write a code to create that string. It does not need to be feature complete like SQL, but it can contain basic functionality that works for your  use case.